# FindCluster only finds cluster "with a little help"

Tags: cluster-analysis

Currently I made some slides to illustrate clustering. As an example I made a point set of two clusters:

```
   {clusters, graph} = Block[{c1, c2, cluster1, cluster2},
   c1 = {1, 2}; 
   cluster1 = (# + c1) & /@ 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5], {10^3, 2}];
   c2 = {3, 3}; 
   cluster2 = (# + c2) & /@ 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5], {10^3, 2}];
   {clusters = Union[cluster1, cluster2],
    Graphics[{{Green, Point[cluster1]}, {Red, Point[cluster2]}}, 
     Frame -> True]}
   ];
graph
```

which looks somewhat like:

[image]

Mathematica is a powerful tool, so I tried a naive approach

```
cls = FindClusters[clusters];
```

... and got:

[image]

Further "experiments" like

```
FindClusters[clusters, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]
```

were all not successful. What worked immediately is

```
FindClusters[clusters, Method -> "Optimize"]
```

which delivers:

[image]

But the method "Optimize" is removed from documentation, see [Question addressing FindClusters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/findclusters-versus-clusteringcomponents)

So the question is: Is there an easy way to find the (obvious) clusters in that case without putting parts of the "solution" (two clusters) in the options of `FindClusters`?