# What is the default method of FindClusters?

Tags: options, cluster-analysis, default

I used `Method -> Automatic` on `FindClusters` and obtain a cluster `autoCts` as below:-

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[12]; rand = RandomReal[1, {30, 2}]];
autoCts = FindClusters[rand, Method -> Automatic];
```

Since I was using `Method -> Automatic`. I want to figure out what is the exact method that I was using in `FindClusters`. As per the documentation, there should be 10 methods except the `Automatic`. Thus I plugged in all of them to see if I can get the same result:-

```
allMethods = {"Agglomerate", "DBSCAN", "NeighborhoodContraction", "JarvisPatrick", "KMeans", "MeanShift", "KMedoids", "SpanningTree","Spectral", "GaussianMixture"};
allCts = Quiet@FindClusters[rand, Method -> #] & /@ allMethods;
checkSame = (# == autoCts) & /@ allCts
```

As you can see, 7 methods give a different output (i.e. `False` in `checkSame`), while 3 methods don't give an output.

How can I determine what method I was really using in `FindClusters`?

Many thanks!

Comment: related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156984/findcluster-only-finds-cluster-with-a-little-help